# Prove that the right shift operator $S(x_1,x_2, \dots) = (0,x_1,x_2,\dots)$ is bounded.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

**Exercise :**

> Let $S: l^1 \to l^1$ be the right-shift operator :
>   $$S(x_1,x_2,\dots) = (0,x_1,x_2,\dots)$$
>   Prove that $S$ is bounded and find its norm.

**Attempt :**

The space $l^1$ is : $$l^1 = \{(x=(x_n) : \sum_{i=1}^\infty x_n < + \infty\}$$

To show that the operator $S$ is bounded, I must show that :

$$\exists \; M>0 : \|Sx\|\leq M\|x\|$$

But I can't really see how to proceed on this particular proof without having any knowledge of the norm that should be used. Shall the norm of $l^1$ space be used ? If so, what does  "find the norm of the operator S" ?

I would **really** appreciate any tips/solutions or clarifications regarding this particular exercise.

**Note :** I have **NOT** been introduced to isometries in my Functional Analysis class yet, so I am looking for an elementary bounded operator approach.

Comment: The shift operator is an isometry, so in particular it is bounded.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff We haven't been introduced to isometries yet in our Functional Analysis course, so I assume we should seek a more elementary approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\|S(x_1,x_2,\dots)\|_1=\|(0,x_1,x_2,\cdots)\|_1=0+|x_1|+|x_2|+\dots = |x_1|+|x_2|+\dots = \|(x_1,x_2,\dots)\|_1.$$

In particular, $$\|S(x_1,x_2,\cdots)\|_1\le 1\cdot \|(x_1,x_2,\cdots)\|_1.$$

This inequality says that $S$ is bounded and $\|S\|\le 1$.

But $S(1,0,0,\dots)=(0,1,0,\dots)$, so $$\|S(1,0,\dots)\|_1 =\|(0,1,0,\dots)\|_1=1=\|(1,0,\dots)\|_1.$$

So $\|S\|=1$

Comment: I cannot really understand what an isometry is, since we haven't been introduced to them yet. Also, what does "find the norm of the operator S" mean ?

Comment: @Rebellos LEt $(X,\|\cdot\|)$ be a Banach space. $T:X\to X$ is an isometry iff $\|Tx\|=\|x\|$ for all $x\in X$

Comment: As I said again, I am really not interested in an isometry approach or terminology. I **must** solve the exercise using an elementary bounded operator approach, as we have **not** been introduced to isometries yet. Also, the second part of my question is not answered, what does **find the norm of the operator S** mean ?

Comment: @Rebellos the fact that it is an isometry is icing on the cake. This answer shows that the operator is bounded via the definition you give.

Comment: @Dave Yeah, I get that. But what about the clarification regarding the last part of the exercise ? Probably it wants to correlate the expression $$\|Sx\| \leq \|S\| \|x\|$$ with the bounded expression and thus $\|S\| =1$ ? (Edit : Just saw the updated answer)

Comment: @Rebellos the $\ell^1$ norm must be used to show boundedness, and for the norm of $S$ have you covered operator norms?

Comment: It's fine, I get it now. It's $$\|S\| = \sup\bigg\{\frac{\|Sx\|}{\|x\|} : x \in X\bigg\}$$ and by the elaboration above, since we have an equality, it's $\|S\| = 1$.

Comment: @Rebellos $\|Sx\|=\|x\|$ only says that $\|S\|\le 1$. You need a vector where you attain the norm to guarantee that $\|S\|=1$.

Comment: @TitoEliatron Oh, nice point ! Understod.

Answer (score 2):

From scratch:

$\vec x=(x_1,x_2,\cdots )$ and  $S(\vec x)=(0,x_1,x_2,\cdots)$ so

$\|\vec x\|=\sum^{\infty}_{i=1}|x_i|$ and $\|S(\vec x)\|=\sum^{\infty}_{i=1}|x_i|=\|\vec x\|.$

Now, $\|S|\|=\sup_x\frac{\|S(\vec x)\|}{\|\vec x\|}=\frac{\|\vec x\|}{\|\vec x\|}=1$.

Therefore, $\|S\|=1$ and, in particular $S$ is bounded.